# Modify EC2 service role so that it can be assumed by an IAM user in the same account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, roles

I have a role `ssm-role` for EC2. I want another IAM user to launch EC2 instance with `ssm-role` attached.

Policy attached with `ssm-role` : `AmazonEC2RoleforSSM`

Trust relationship for `ssm-role`:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com",
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<ACC_ID>:user/test-user"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have added the following inline policy for the user who wants to assume `ssm-role`:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "test",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::<ACC_ID>:role/ssm-role"
        }
    ]
}
```

Despite these, `test-user` is not able to launch EC2 with `ssm-role` attached.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Note: test-user has `EC2FullAccess`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To launch an Amazon EC2 instance with an attached role, the IAM User making the request needs to have `iam:PassRole` permissions for the given role.

This is required to prevent a potential "elevation of authority" situation, such as:

- A user has limited permissions
- They launch an EC2 instance, specifying a Role that has elevated privileges
- They login to the EC2 instance and use the privileges of the Role to perform functions that they would not normally be permitted to do

Thus, a user must have `iam:PassRole` permissions for the given role (at minimum) to be able to launch an instance that uses that role.

See: [Granting a User Permissions to Pass a Role to an AWS Service - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_passrole.html)